# The Coverage field from ApexCodeCoverageAggregate isn't returning coverage lines in Spring '16 (v37.0)

Tags: soap, tooling-api, spring16

I've previously used the SOAP version of the Tooling API to run the following SOQL query to get the aggregate code coverage for an Apex class.

> SELECT ApexClassOrTriggerId, ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, Coverage 
>            FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate where ApexClassOrTriggerId = '01p400000005cBjAAI'

I noticed that once I upgraded from v36.0 to v37.0 (Spring '16) of the Tooling API the [Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcodecoverageaggregate.htm) stopped including the `coveredLines` and `uncoveredLines`. They were just null when checked in .NET code.

If I make the SOAP call directly I can see them coming back. 
[image]

Same with the equivalent REST API call.
[image]

Why did they stop working in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update for Winter `17 Patch 14.2.**

This appears to be resolved as the `coveredLines` and `uncoveredLines` in the response are now in the `"urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com"` namespace.

[image: Namespace changes]

---

I suspect this is a bug in the Tooling API that was introduced in Spring '16.

If you diff the v36.0 to v37.0 Tooling API WSDL a number of elements changed namespace from 
`tns: (xmlns:tns="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com")`
to
`ens: (xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.tooling.soap.sforce.com")`

For ApexCodeCoverageAggregate, it extends sObject which changed namespace. Also, a number of other elements on the complexType also changed (ApexClassOrTrigger, CreatedBy, LastModifiedBy). However, `Coverage` remained in the older **tns** namespace.

[image]

The SOAP response shows the problem. The Coverage is in the **sf** namespace (*xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.tooling.soap.sforce.com"*) rather than the expected default namespace for the response (*xmlns="urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com"*)

[image]

Raised as support case 14656682.